# Implement CSP for indiviual pages in NUXT JS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, content-security-policy

I had a requirement in a project of mine using NUXT JS to add CSP for a particular page only. The CSP headers that we provide should also be dyanamic. I looked through various articles which mentioned implementing CSP using the nuxt.config.js file for the entire NUXT application. Also if I change the values in the CSP property I need to restart the server each time (Also not sure about how to implement that). Is the above requirement possible to implement in NUXT..?